# update a parent key column where there are nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

Hopefully some can help.What I want to achieve here is to update the `TS_PARENT_TS_ID` column with the `TS_ID column(Primary Key)`. using row 2 and 3 as examples, if you take a look at column name `(TS_TERM_TYPE_NAME)`, You have `"MAIN"` directly under it (row 3) is `"RELATED"`. These are both related to each other, hence should have the same foreign keys in column `(TS_PARENT_TS_ID)`, So basically they should both have a value of 1 in the `(TS_PARENT_TS_ID)` column. Another way to think about this is, in  `TS_TERM_TYPE_NAME` column ALL `"MAIN"` that are followed with `"RELATED(s)"`  belong to the same family and hence, should have the same  `(TS_PARENT_TS_ID)`. To state another example, please see row (7-9). The Primary Key is 4(TS_ID), hence the `(TS_PARENT_TS_ID)` would be 4 for the `"MAIN"` and the 2 following "RELATED" (row 8 and 9)

-See Screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The key words in your question are "directly under" and "same family". What decides about belonging to the same groups? Your data suggests that it is the same `TS_NOTATION` (and/or msg). If so then you can use `merge`:

```
merge into agriculture a
using (select ts_notation, min(ts_parent_ts_id) id
         from agriculture 
         where ts_term_type_name = 'RELATED'
         group by ts_notation) b
on (a.ts_notation = b.ts_notation and a.ts_term_type_name = 'MAIN')
when matched then update set a.ts_parent_ts_id = b.id
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d31ea2f72a79e01399a37af202ac1e97)</sup>**

Comment: Hello Ponder, Thanks for the response, but does this only apply to "AGRICULTURE" and its RELATED terms? I have thousands of "MAIN and "RELATED" terms that need

Comment: `agriculture` is name of the table, use your table name instead. This statement will update all  'MAIN' rows for which it finds proper `RELATED` row. Please look at provided dbfiddle to see an example.

Comment: Hello Ponder, are we able to connect? Basically the query does seem to be working. if you able, my email is phlexzibit_x@yahoo.com.

Comment: Nope, I have not much time :) If you have another questions please post them in separate topics. This way you have greater chance someone answers. Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved problem, but I do not insist ;-) And do not post images containing data, copy-paste as text.